# Renaming a Folder using Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I am currently trying to Rename the Folder that was recently created, i know there is a command called REN (or) RENAME but it is used to rename a file and not the Folder.

```
Below is the code that i am working to achieve this.

    for %%# in ("%mask%_*") do (
     if not exist "%destination_dir%\%mask%" mkdir "%destination_dir%\%mask%"
     move /y "%%~#" "%destination_dir%\%mask%"
     if exist "%destination_dir%\%mask%" ren "%destination_dir%\%mask%_%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%-%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%"
    )
```

How to achieve this.?

Comment: http://www.computerhope.com/renamehl.htm ? Just use the folder name, should work....

Comment: i am getting Syntax of the command is incorrect. below is the line that i have added if exist "%destination_dir%\%mask%" rename "%destination_dir%\%mask%_%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%-%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%"

Comment: ren does folders too.

Comment: Why not create the folder with the correct name in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your batch code in line starting with `if exist` the command **ren** is started just with 1 parameter. So the second parameter with new name for folder/file is missing. Please note that the second parameter must be always just the new name of file/folder without path.

Your batch code should be most likely:

```
for %%# in ("%mask%_*") do (
     if not exist "%destination_dir%\%mask%" mkdir "%destination_dir%\%mask%"
     move /y "%%~#" "%destination_dir%\%mask%"
     if exist "%destination_dir%\%mask%" ren "%destination_dir%\%mask%" "%mask%_%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%-%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%"
)
```